# What data can you actually get realtime during an Apple Watch workout?

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit, watchos

What data can you actually get during an Apple Watch workout?

There seems to be a lot of different [quantity type objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier) that you can request read access to but what can I actually get live from the Apple Watch during a workout session.

These are the ones I'm sure of:

- Heart Rate
- Active Energy Burned
- Distance Walking/Running

Comment: I'd say you linked to your answer. You can return live updates by reading HKStatistics values from whatever HKQuantityType you specify. If you'd like help with how to do this, post some code of what you have so far and I'm happy to help.

Comment: But an Apple Watch wouldn't be able to get live updates of things like bodyMass or bloodGlucose so shouldn't there just be a subset of types that would actually apply?